# i want to get images from folder and upload image into another folder without any input type file?

Tags: php, mysql

i want to get images from folder and upload image into another folder without any input type file? but i'm getting images from admin/uploads now

**here my page code**

```
<?php
$size = 200; // the thumbnail height
     $filedir = 'uploads/'; // the directory for the original image
     $thumbdir = 'uploads/'; // the directory for the thumbnail image
     $prefix = 'small0_'; // the prefix to be added to the original name
     $maxfile = '2000000';
     $mode = '0666';
     $rnd_1 = rand(11111,99999); 

     $userfile_name= $rnd_1.'_'.$_FILES['image']["name"];
     $userfile_tmp = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
     $userfile_size = $_FILES['image']['size'];
     $userfile_type = $_FILES['image']['type'];
     if (isset($_FILES['image']['name'])) 
     {
         $prod_img = $filedir.$userfile_name;
         $prod_img_thumb = $thumbdir.$prefix.$userfile_name;
         move_uploaded_file($userfile_tmp, $prod_img);
         chmod ($prod_img, octdec($mode));
         $sizes = getimagesize($prod_img);
        $aspect_ratio = $sizes[1]/$sizes[0]; 
         if ($sizes[1] <= $size)
         {

             $new_width = '500';
             $new_height = '500';
         }else{

             $new_width = '500';
             $new_height = '500';
         }
             $destimg=ImageCreateTrueColor($new_width,$new_height)
             or die('Problem In Creating image');

           $srcimg=ImageCreateFromJPEG($prod_img)
         or $srcimg=ImageCreateFromPNG($prod_img)
         or $srcimg=ImageCreateFromGIF($prod_img)
             or die('Problem In opening Source Image0');
         if(function_exists('imagecopyresampled'))
         {
             imagecopyresampled($destimg,$srcimg,0,0,0,0,$new_width,$new_height,ImageSX($srcimg),ImageSY($srcimg))
             or die('Problem In resizing');
         }else{
             Imagecopyresized($destimg,$srcimg,0,0,0,0,$new_width,$new_height,ImageSX($srcimg),ImageSY($srcimg))
             or die('Problem In resizing');
         }
         ImageJPEG($destimg,$prod_img_thumb,90)
             or die('Problem In saving');
     }
?>

 <img name="image" id="image" src="admin/uploads/small0_<?php echo $image?>"   width="150" height="150">
```

**Me Getting Image From admin/upload now i want to movie shopping cart product images into another folder without input type file**

Answer (score 0):

If it is already on the server, [`rename`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php) should do the trick.

Comment: i see you are calling `move_uploaded_file` is it not moving it into the right folder?

Comment: this script working admin panel but with input type file but i want this script will work in shopping cart page without input type file

Comment: @FarhanDharsi i'm not sure what you are asking.

Comment: i want to move shopping product images without input type file

Comment: try the `rename` method i posted.